# Cannot connect to docker container (localhost) MAC m1 ARM

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I am running a vue application, after running and building without problems i try to connect to the application that is being run on localhost:8080. I cannot find the application. I have tried several things but none working. Any suggestions? What do you need from me. Ask and ill will update my question.

******* Docker Compose yaml file

```
    version: '3'
services:
  servicehub_backend:
    build:
      context: ../servicehub-backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-hotswap
    user: "${MYUID}:${MYGID}"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - "../servicehub-backend/:/opt/app-root/"
  servicehub_front:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-hotswap
    user: "${MYUID}:${MYGID}"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - "./:/opt/app-root/src/"
```

Comment: Post your docker-compose.yaml file

Comment: did you set your port mappings like

```-p 8080:8080```

Comment: i have not run any commands, i am running a project for my company which works for every other member in the team but mine is mac so i cannot connect. Is there a specific file i can check if the port mappings are set there? @ozgenbaris

Comment: @AppCodah please take a look at the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

You should map your containers port 8080 to your host machine's 8080

Comment: Host networking generally disables Docker's networking layer.  It's rarely necessary, and it doesn't work on systems using Docker Desktop or other VM-based solutions.  If you delete `network_mode: host` and correctly set up `ports:`, does it work better?  You'll have at least four different `localhost` in this setup, which one is the target process running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward traffic from a port on your machine to port 8080 in the container ([docker compose ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)). In your client add

```
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Then you contact the container on `localhost:8080`.